# How to modfiy environment.rb through sh script? (i.e. modify line in file through script?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell

I'm trying to write a sh script to make a rails apps, however due to different conflict, I need to modify my environment.rb file to comment out the rails version. So my question is how do I had '#' to line 8 of environment.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways, but sed is the first hammer that came to mind:

```
sed 's/^\(RAILS_GEM_VERSION.*\)$/# \1/' -i '.backup' config/environment.rb
```

Or even in ruby:

```
ruby -pi  -e 'print "# " if $_ =~ /^RAILS_GEM_VERSION/' config/environment.rb
```

Comment: I've got another similar question. I'm trying to add config.gem "newrelic_rpm" However the double quotes are giving me trouble. Any suggestions?

Comment: This may do it (untested):
ruby -i -e 'puts $_; puts %q{  config.gem "newrelic_rpm"} if $_=~ /^Rails::Initializer\.run/'

Answer (score 1):

to comment line 8

```
awk 'NR==8{$0="#"$0}1' config/environment.rb >temp
mv temp config/environment.rb
```

to comment line with RAILS_GEM_VERSION

```
awk '/RAILS_GEM_VERSION/{gsub(/^RAILS_GEM_VERSION/,"#RAILS_GEM_VERSION") }1' config/environment.rb >temp
mv temp config/environment.rb
```

and depending on where you want to add config.gem "newrelic_rpm", say you want to add at the end of the file, then just use  >>

```
echo 'config.gem="newrelic_rpm"' >> config/environment.rb
```